Torsion points of algebraic groups
Let $G$ be an algebraic group over an algebraically closed field $k$. Each of its irreducible components is the translate of the connected component for the identity $G^o$ by some point. Can said points always be chosen to be torsion? This is: does every irreducible component of an algebraic group contain a torsion point?

It depends on what you mean by "algebraic group"; for example is the constant group scheme $\mathbb{Z}$ an algebraic group?

@QiaochuYuan I use the definition in Milne's Algebraic Groups. That is, a group scheme of finite type over a field
